# Horizontal xor of two SSE values

Tags: c, sse, xor

I would need to do horizontal xor of two 128bit integers (by 32bit integers) and combine the results to one 64bit integer. So operation like this:

```
uint32_t x0[4];
uint32_t x1[4];

uint32_t xor0 = x0[0];
uint32_t xor1 = x1[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
    xor0 ^= x0[i];
    xor1 ^= x1[i];
}
uint64_t xor = uint64_t(xor1) << 32 | xor0;
```

I finally found following code, that seems to work:

```
__m128i x0 = ...;
__m128i x1 = ...;

__m128i xor64_0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(x0, x1);
__m128i xor64_1 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(x0, x1);

__m128i xor64 = _mm_xor_si128(xor64_0, xor64_1);
__m128i xor32_0 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(xor64, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));
__m128i xor32_1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(xor64, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 3, 1));
__m128i xor32 = _mm_xor_si128(xor32_0, xor32_1);

uint64_t xor = _mm_cvtsi128_si64(xor32);
```

Is this the fastest possible implementation? Would it make sense to combine integer and floating-point operations, like _mm_movehdup_ps(.) ?

Comment: This will run faster in general-purpose registers than vector registers.

Comment: I think you should demostrate processing of large array (post code used in a loop).

Comment: From what you have shown so far I don't see why you are using SIMD. If you want some help you should explain more of what you are doing. Are you really using 128-bit integers? What else are you doing with them? E.g are you doing multiplication and addition with them? Why do you store them in four 32-bit integers rather than two 64-bit integers.

Comment: Your operation would be most efficient if you did it on four 128-bit integers using two SSE registers with one with the low 64-bits and one with the high 64-bits.